# Qlikview data export - Python

Tags: python, excel, download, export, qlikview

I'm not very knowledgeable on the subject ... I need to export a table from qlikviewer (where there is already a "Send to Excel" button). Initially I tried with Selenium, but arrived at the "second click" it does not find the text I need to filter. Searching on the net I discovered that for qlick services there are APIs, but I don't understand how to use them, as I enter qlik with credentials and on an address, I don't have the possibility to have qlick desktop. Can anyone help me?

Just to make you understand (I hope).
Using the command:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath ("// div [@ id = '34 ']"). text
```

I find the text I click, but using:

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text ()
```

I can't click in the same value

Comment: do you have access to source data? or can download qvw file with dashboard? or contact with dashboard owner? otherwise it will be difficult. If you have access to qvw it is really easy...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.